# Docker: reattach to `docker exec` process

Tags: docker

If I use `docker exec` to fire up a shell,

```
docker exec -ti <CONTAINER> /bin/bash
```

I could use Ctrl+p Ctrl+q to detach this shell process. Then this shell is still running inside the container, but how can I reattach to that one particular shell (the one started by `docker exec`, not `docker run`)?

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, this is not possible yet; see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9527). I've also wanted this functionality, but at the moment it seems like there's no direct way to do this.

A workaround has been proposed, to take care of the case where you're accessing a box via `ssh` and running `docker exec` on the remote box (or, for the case where your terminal emulator is unstable and may crash on you): [Always run your `docker exec` commands inside `screen` or `tmux`.](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9527#issuecomment-213358760) If you do this, whenever you get detached from the `screen`/`tmux` session, you can re-attach to it later and still have your `docker exec` commands accessible. (this is a bit different than what was [suggested by @vodolaz095](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069218/docker-reattach-to-docker-exec-process#comment57864590_35070691), since it involves running `screen` or `tmux` *outside* the container, making it suitable for use with containers that don't run `screen`/`tmux` as their main process)

Answer (score 6):

`docker exec` is specifically for running new things in an already started container, be it a shell or some other process.

`docker attach` is for attaching to a running process, so you can use only one instance of shell.

Run you container(process)

```
docker run -tid --name <CONTAINER> <IMAGE>:<TAG> bin/bash
```

Then

```
docker attach <CONTAINER>
```

To detach <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>

On this way you can attach and detach multiple times with only one instance of shell

Comment: also you can use tools like `tmux` or `screen` and run them inside the container

Comment: Sorry this wasn't the answer I was looking for. I can attach to the main shell with no problem, as described above. But I want to reattach to the second shell that I launched with `docker exec` and now got detached.

Comment: I don't think there is way to do that now, because the `exec` command is not designed to that

Comment: As suggested @vodolaz095, if I were you I would use `tmux`. You can reattach from previous "bash session" (you can also split your bash screen into multiple panels and tabs).
**This does not answer your question though!** .. as you asked how to reattached to a previous process (not start a new one to _plug into a previous shell session_.